# Simple count system. PHP/.TXT file

Tags: php, file

I have the following simple count, system and I have 2 things, that I can't do.
Here is my count.php file:

```
<?php
if (file_exists('admin/all_count.txt')){
    $fil = fopen('admin/all_count.txt', r);
    $dat = fread($fil, filesize('admin/all_count.txt'));
    echo $dat+1;
    fclose($fil);
    $fil = fopen('admin/all_count.txt', w);
    fwrite($fil, $dat+1);
}
else 
{
    $fil = fopen('admin/all_count.txt', w);
    fwrite($fil, 1);
    echo '1';
    fclose($fil);
}
?>
```

Here is the content of the all_count.txt file (but I don't think you need it, anyway):

```
81
```

Questions:-

1. So to make count.php work, I place `<?php include("count.php");
   ?>` inside the page which counts I would like to count, BUT where I
   put this include, it is showing the actual content of all_count.txt
   file in the webpage, which I would like to be hidden.
2. I would like to make a script that makes the content of
       the all_count.txt file to zero. Thank you guys in advance.

I tried this for making it zero a week ago, but didn't work:
I tried this for make it zero, and didn't work:
zero.php:

```
<?php
if (file_exists('admin/all_count.txt')){
    $fil = fopen('admin/all_count.txt', r);
    $dat = fread($fil, filesize('admin/all_count.txt'));
    $dat-$dat;
    fclose($fil);
    $fil = fopen('admin/all_count.txt', w);
    fwrite($fil, $dat-$dat);
}
else 
{
    $fil = fopen('admin/all_count.txt', w);
    fwrite($fil, 0);
    echo '0';
    fclose($fil);
}
?>
```

Comment: Because of this line: echo $dat+1; remove "echo"

Comment: If you don't want anything to show in your page you shouldn't `echo` it out

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Consider using a database for this. You'll have to deal with concurrency access issues with the file.
2. You can open your file once for reading and writing
3. You should enclose 'r' and 'w' access modifiers into the quotes
4. You should not echo it (if you don't want the output)
5. in order to zero the content of the file oyu can just do

   file_put_contents('admin/all_count.txt','0');
6. You can just use file_get_contents/file_put_contents - I think it will be easier for you.

Answer (score 1):

1. Don't use `echo` if you don't want stuff to show up on your page.
2. you already have a way to write the count to your txt file, why wouldn't you be able to just write 0 to it?

Comment: I tried to edit it and make to 0 a week ago, but I failed somehow.